# Proof that a matrix consisting of minima is positive-semidefinite

Tags: symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

I have a Matrix symmetric, non-negative Matrix $\pmb{A} \in {\mathbb{N}_0}^{N\times N}$.

It is defined as follows:
$$\pmb{A}=\left[\begin{matrix}
\min(x_1,x_1) & \dots &\min(x_1,x_N)\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\min(x_N, x_1) & \dots & \min(x_N, x_N)
\end{matrix}\right]$$
where $x_n\in\mathbb{N}_0$.

How can I prove that the matrix is positive-semidefinite?

My approach so far starts at
$$\pmb{A}\succcurlyeq0 \iff \vec{x}^T\pmb{A}\vec{x} \ge 0$$
$$\vec{x}^T\pmb{A}\vec{x} = \sum_i^N\sum_j^N A_{ij}x_ix_j\ge0$$
Which I have decomposed using the properties of the matrix into
$\sum_k^NA_{kk}x_k^2 + 2\sum_{i=2}^N\sum_{j=1}^{i-1}A_{ij}x_ix_j\ge0$, but I am having trouble getting any further.

Comment: Diagonally dominant is usually defined differently. This claim with these definitios is wrong. For instance `[[2,2,0],[2,2,2],[0,2,2]]` has an eigenvalue `-0.82842712`.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @LutzLehmann thanks for the comment, I forgot to mention one important property of the matrix, that your example would violate. Is there a way to show positive semi-definiteness with the added property?

Comment: @Till The extra condition does not help. The eigenvalues will only change slightly if you perturb the entries. So just change the zeros to 0.00001 or something like that, and the eigenvalue will remain negative. Note that the conventional definition of diagonally dominant is that the diagonal entry is greater than the whole row combined, not just each entry individually. In that case the result does hold; one way to prove is is using the Gershgorin circle theorem

Comment: @NickAlger, very good point although the matrix only has natural numbers as elements, the matrix `[[2,2,1],[2,2,2],[1,2,2]]` still is not positive semi-definite. I have reframed my question to better reflect the actual properties of the matrix. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M := \max_i x_i$. If we define the map $\phi: \{0, \ldots, M\} \to \{0, 1\}^{M+1}$ by $$\phi(x) = (\mathbf{1}\{x \le 0\}, \mathbf{1}\{x \le 1\}, \mathbf{1}\{x \le 2\}, \ldots, \mathbf{1}\{x \le M\}),$$
we have $\min(x_i, x_j) = \langle \phi(x_i), \phi(x_j) \rangle$.

So for any vector $v$, we have
$$v^\top A v = \sum_i \sum_j v_i v_j \langle \phi(x_i), \phi(x_j)\rangle
= \left\langle \sum_i v_i \phi(x_i), \sum_j v_j \phi(x_j)\right\rangle
= \left\|\sum_i v_i \phi(x_i)\right\|^2 \ge 0.$$

Comment: This can even be extended to non-integer $x_i$ by having $\phi_i(t)={\bf 1}_{[0,x_i]}(t)$ and using the $L^2$ scalar product to get $v^TAv=\|\sum v_i\phi_i\|^2_{L^2}$